# Setting initial selected index of JComboBox to -1 or nothing

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, listcellrenderer

I recently started learning `ListCellRenderer` for `JComboBox` and finally got the basic idea. However, I can't set the initial state or initial selected item of combo box to `null` (or selected index to -1). I would like to set it to -1 so that when the form loads, nothing is selected yet until user clicks on the drop down to select an item.

I tried using the `comboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1)` and `comboBox.setSelectedItem(null)`

```
        GradeLevelDaoImpl gldi = new GradeLevelDaoImpl();
        DefaultComboBoxModel gradeLevelModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(gldi.getAllActiveGradeLevels().toArray());
        jcmbGradeLevel.setModel(gradeLevelModel);
        jcmbGradeLevel.setRenderer(new JComboBoxRenderer());
        jcmbGradeLevel.setSelectedItem(null); //doesn't work
        jcmbGradeLevel.setSelectedIndex(-1); //doesn't work
```

Like so.

And here's what I keep getting when I launch the form.

[image]

`GradeLevel` combo box is still selected. Index is at 0;

Here's my renderer.

```
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        //Class value conversion to getString value using getter

        if (value instanceof SchoolYear) {
            this.setText("" + ((SchoolYear) value).getStart());
        }
        if (value instanceof GradeLevel) {

            this.setText("" + ((GradeLevel) value).getGradelevel());
        }
        if (value instanceof PaymentTerm) {
            this.setText("" + ((PaymentTerm) value).getPaymentTerm());
        }
        if (value instanceof FeeCategory) {
            this.setText("" + ((FeeCategory) value).getFeeCategory());
        }

        //selection formatting
        if (isSelected) {
            this.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            //this.setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
            this.setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
        } else {
            this.setBackground(list.getBackground());
            this.setForeground(list.getForeground());

        }

        if ((isSelected) && (cellHasFocus)) {
            this.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        } else {
            this.setBorder(null);
        }
        return this;
    }
```

I even tried to set the `index` parameter to -1. `index = -1;` with no success.
Tried `list.setSelectedIndex(-1)`, still won't work.

Any advice or solution?

Comment: 1) `if (isSelected) {
            this.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);` It doesn't look yellow here. Does it show yellow when an item is selected using the drop-down? 2) Why not set the first value is 'please select' (or whatever means that to the user)? 3) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: What happens when the `value` is not an instance of `ShoolYear`, `GradeLevel`, `PaymentTerm`, `FeeCategory`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I get the string representation of gradelevel which is 12.

Comment: @p3ace Now, ask yourself "why"?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay, I get it. I tried couple of things here. So I now understand that it will only render objects that are tested through if-else-if. Otherwise, it won't render it. I don't know but I hope this isn't too bad for a question. I appreciate the help as always. Thanks.

Comment: @p3ace Well, it will render what ever was last set ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah. Still lots of things to learn. I'll look into other renderers. B-) Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting a "default" value for the renderer (or at least you're not checking to see if the `value` is `null`).

Remember, this is shared with ALL the elements in the component, so you MUST configure ALL the properties which might be changed between different object values

```
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    //Class value conversion to getString value using getter

    if (value instanceof SchoolYear) {
        this.setText("" + ((SchoolYear) value).getStart());
    } else if (value instanceof GradeLevel) {
        this.setText("" + ((GradeLevel) value).getGradelevel());
    } else if (value instanceof PaymentTerm) {
        this.setText("" + ((PaymentTerm) value).getPaymentTerm());
    } else if (value instanceof FeeCategory) {
        this.setText("" + ((FeeCategory) value).getFeeCategory());
    } else {
        this.setText("---");
    }

    //selection formatting
    if (isSelected) {
        this.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        //this.setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
        this.setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
    } else {
        this.setBackground(list.getBackground());
        this.setForeground(list.getForeground());

    }

    if ((isSelected) && (cellHasFocus)) {
        this.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
    } else {
        this.setBorder(null);
    }
    return this;
}
```

This will display `---` when the value is not one of the values you are prepared to render